# Javascript not running correctly on content within asp.net updatepanel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a function which adds a custon tooltip to certain dates on a jquery datepicker when the user hovers over them. This is working fine in a normal html page, but I need to make it work on a .net page with an updatepanel...

Here's my code which works...

```
<input class='propertyAvailabilityCal' />

<select name="startDates"  id="startDates" class="startdates">
    <option selected="selected" value="%">%</option>
    <option value="2013, 11, 01">C1</option>
    <option value="2013, 11, 08">C1</option>
    <option value="2013, 11, 11">C1</option>
    <option value="2013, 11, 18">C1</option>
    <option value="2013, 11, 29">C1</option>

</select>
```

Javascript...

```
function dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
  // Discard the time and time-zone information.
  var utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());
  var utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());

  return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}

var firstStartDate;

$('.propertyAvailabilityCal').datepicker({

        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: '+2Y',
        numberOfMonths: 1,

        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
            startDates = [];            
            selectdatesElem = $(input).siblings("select.startdates");   
            firstStartDate = selectdatesElem.find("option:eq(1)").val().split(', ');
            $(input).datepicker('option','defaultDate',dateDiffInDays(new Date(), new Date(parseInt(firstStartDate[1], 10) + "/" + parseInt(firstStartDate[2], 10) + "/" + parseInt(firstStartDate[0], 10))));

            $(input).siblings("select.startdates").find("option").each( function() {
                  startdateParts = $(this).val().split(', ');
                  startDates.push(startdateParts[0] + ", " + (parseInt(startdateParts[1], 10)-1) + ", " + parseInt(startdateParts[2], 10));
            }); 

        },

        beforeShowDay: function(date) {         
            for (i = 0; i < startDates.length; i++) {
                  if (date.getFullYear()+", "+date.getMonth()+", "+date.getDate() == startDates[i]) {
                        return [true, 'eventDay',"someText"];
                  }
            }           
            return [false, ''];
        }
    });

$(document).on("mouseover", "td.eventDay", function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("ui-datepicker-days-cell-over")){
        $(this).removeClass('ui-datepicker-days-cell-over').find('a').removeClass('ui-state-hover');
    }
    else{
        $(this).data("title", { popit: $(this).attr("title") }).removeAttr("title").css("position","relative");
            if($(this).data("title").popit) {
                $(this).append("<span class='detailsPopup' style='position:absolute; z-index:5;'>"+$(this).data("title").popit+"</span>");
            }
    }
    });

$(document).on("mouseleave", "td.eventDay", function() {
        $(this).data("title", { popit: $(this).find(".detailsPopup").html() });
        $(this).attr("title", $(this).data("title").popit);
        $(this).find(".detailsPopup").remove();
    });
```

But if replace the input with an asp:textbox which is not visible on the page until a button is clicked and place it all within an asp.net updatepanel, the custon tooltip on the first available date popups up without hovering (because this is set to be the default date). Is seems to be ignoring the `if($(this).hasClass("ui-datepicker-days-cell-over")){` part of the mouseover event.

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<script runat="server">


Sub CheckAvailability(ByVal Sender as Object, ByVal E as EventArgs)
    mydate.Visible = True
    mybutton.Visible = False
End Sub

</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>- jsFiddle demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.tomandjayne.co.uk/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.tomandjayne.co.uk/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/css/result-light.css">
<style type='text/css'></style>
<script type='text/javascript'>

//DATE DIFFERENCE FUNCTION FOR PROPERTY LEVEL DATEPICKER FIRST DATE
var firstStartDate;
function dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
  // Discard the time and time-zone information.
  var utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());
  var utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());

  return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}

function pageLoad() {

$('.propertyAvailabilityCal').datepicker({

        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: '+2Y',
        numberOfMonths: 1,

        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
            startDates = [];            
            selectdatesElem = $(input).siblings("select.startdates");   
            firstStartDate = selectdatesElem.find("option:eq(1)").val().split(', ');
            $(input).datepicker('option','defaultDate',dateDiffInDays(new Date(), new Date(parseInt(firstStartDate[1], 10) + "/" + parseInt(firstStartDate[2], 10) + "/" + parseInt(firstStartDate[0], 10))));

            $(input).siblings("select.startdates").find("option").each( function() {
                  startdateParts = $(this).val().split(', ');
                  startDates.push(startdateParts[0] + ", " + (parseInt(startdateParts[1], 10)-1) + ", " + parseInt(startdateParts[2], 10));
            }); 

        },

        beforeShowDay: function(date) {         
            for (i = 0; i < startDates.length; i++) {
                  if (date.getFullYear()+", "+date.getMonth()+", "+date.getDate() == startDates[i]) {
                        return [true, 'eventDay',"someText"];
                  }
            }           
            return [false, ''];
        }
    });

    $(document).on("mouseover", "td.eventDay", function() {
        if($(this).hasClass("ui-datepicker-days-cell-over")){
            //alert("do nothing");
            $(this).removeClass('ui-datepicker-days-cell-over').find("a").removeClass('ui-state-hover');
            //$(this).find("span.detailsPopup").remove();
        }
        else{
            $(this).data("title", { popit: $(this).attr("title") }).removeAttr("title").css("position","relative");
            if($(this).data("title").popit) {
                $(this).append("<span class='detailsPopup' style='position:absolute; z-index:5;'>"+$(this).data("title").popit+"</span>");
            }
        }
    });

    $(document).on("mouseleave", "td.eventDay", function() {
        $(this).data("title", { popit: $(this).find(".detailsPopup").html() });
        $(this).attr("title", $(this).data("title").popit);
        $(this).find(".detailsPopup").remove();
    }); 

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanelMaster" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
  <ContentTemplate>


<select class="startdates">
  <option selected="selected" value="%">%</option>
  <option value="2013, 12, 28">1</option>
  <option value="2014, 11, 15">1</option>
  <option value="2014, 11, 22">1</option>
  <option value="2014, 12, 13">1</option>
  <option value="2014, 12, 20">1</option>
  <option value="2014, 12, 27">1</option>
  <option value="2015, 01, 03">1</option>
  <option value="2015, 01, 10">1</option>
  <option value="2015, 01, 17">1</option>
  <option value="2015, 01, 24">1</option>
  <option value="2015, 01, 31">1</option>
  <option value="2015, 02, 07">1</option>
  <option value="2015, 02, 14">1</option>
  <option value="2015, 02, 21">1</option>
  <option value="2015, 02, 28">1</option>
  <option value="2015, 03, 14">1</option>
  <option value="2015, 03, 21">1</option>
  <option value="2015, 03, 28">1</option>
  <option value="2015, 04, 04">1</option>
  <option value="2015, 07, 04">1</option>
</select>

<asp:Textbox CssClass="propertyAvailabilityCal" runat="server" ID="mydate" Visible="false" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="mybutton" OnClick="CheckAvailability" Text="CHECK AVAILABILITY" CausesValidation="false" />

  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And I've wrapped my datepicker code in a `function pageLoad() { ... }`

I've tried to simplify this as much as I can but I fear it might still not make sense. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

OK, I think I'm some way towards working it out... It seems to be running the mouseover event twice, once on an existing hidden datepicker and again when the datepicker is shown. So the second time it is run, the classes have already been removed so it shows the tooltip.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Are you getting any errors on console?

Comment: none... the problem is that the tooltip on the first date appears when the datepicker opens without needing to hover

Comment: Do you get the tooltip when you hover over other dates? Does the first tooltip goes away after that?

Comment: Yeah, it works fine other than the fact that the first tooltip appears without the need to be hovered (due to the fact that it's set to the default date). But without it being in an updatepanel removing the class prevents that from happening. It's not prevented in this case though.

Comment: iF It is not happeening on its own it might be a a script conflict which you can solve by using this link http://meetups.jquery.com/group/jquerypuertorico/forum/topics/best-way-to-register-jquery

Comment: Or alternatively, you can manually hide all the tooltips on datepicker- on show event

Comment: @writeToBhuwan I've included a complete version of my .net code so you might be able to replicate the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

write your code in `pageLoad` event instead of DOM ready:

```
function pageLoad(sender,args){
    // Code that should get executed again after partial postback
}
```

Comment: Sorry... should have mentioned that I've done that... I'll edit question now